# python ctypes to pass a pointer to a pointer to a struct dynamically allocating

Tags: python, pointers, struct, ctypes, dynamic-arrays

I'm attempting to use python ctypes to pass the appropriate variables and pointers to a function in a DLL file.

Immediately below is the function description provided in the DLL documentation:

> Prototype: Picam_GetAvailableDemoCameraModels( const PicamModel** model_array, piint*                      model_count )
>
> Description: Returns an allocated array of software-simulated camera models in model_array whose number of items is in model_count
>
> Notes: model_array is allocated by picam and must be freed with
> Picam_DestroyModels.

Further note that piint is mapped to an integer and model_array is mapped to a struct.  My python syntax for doing this is as follows:

```
PicamStringSize_SensorName = PicamStringSize_SerialNumber = 64
PicamModel = PicamComputerInterface = ctypes.c_int
pichar = ctypes.c_char
piint = ctypes.c_int

class PicamCameraID(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("model", PicamModel),
        ("computer_interface", PicamComputerInterface),
        ("sensor_name", pichar * PicamStringSize_SensorName),
        ("serial_number", pichar * PicamStringSize_SerialNumber)]
```

I am then trying to call the function as follows:

```
"""Picam_GetAvailableDemoCameraModels( const PicamModel** model_array,
                                       piint* model_count )"""
model_count = ctypes.c_int()

x = PicamCameraID()

model_array = pointer(pointer(x))

err = picam.Picam_GetAvailableDemoCameraModels( model_array, pointer(model_count))
```

After running this, I am able to read the model_count variable (which tells me there are 133 items in it) and I am able to access the contents of model_array, but the contents are incorrect or garbage, e.g.

```
model_count
c_long(133)
model_array[5].contents.sensor_name
'@~\xe7\x02'
```

I think I'm doing something wrong to the effect of handling the pointers (double-pointer?) incorrectly, but I can't determine where I am straying from the defined syntax.

It seems to me that my syntax is passing in a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-struct, **BUT** I expect the result to be an *array* of the struct (PicamCameraID).  If it was just a struct, I could only have 1 model in the array.  However, I don't know how many models are in the array until after the function runs... and I'm not sure how to (or even if I must) deal with that.

Any insights would be much appreciated and please let me know if I can elaborate anywhere.

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python and ctypes: how to correctly pass "pointer-to-pointer" into DLL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213095/python-and-ctypes-how-to-correctly-pass-pointer-to-pointer-into-dll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question based on an old post

```
getDemos = picam.Picam_GetAvailableDemoCameraModels
getDemos.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(PicamCameraID)) , ctypes.POINTER(piint)]
mem = ctypes.POINTER(PicamCameraID)()
size = ctypes.c_int(0)
getDemos(ctypes.byref(mem), ctypes.byref(size))
print size.value
```

see [Python and ctypes: how to correctly pass "pointer-to-pointer" into DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213095/python-and-ctypes-how-to-correctly-pass-pointer-to-pointer-into-dll) for more details