# Python Ctypes enumerate SessionId's

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ctypes

I have the following code to get the username associated with a session id:

```
ppBuffer = ctypes.c_wchar_p()
pBytesReturned = ctypes.c_ulong()
ctypes.windll.wtsapi32.WTSQuerySessionInformationW(0, SessionId, 5, ctypes.byref(ppBuffer), ctypes.byref(pBytesReturned))
logging.info(f'Username: {ppBuffer.value}')
```

---

I am having issues trying to enumerate through "WTSEnumerateSessionsW" to get an array of SessionId's and State's

I have gotten as far as:

```
class WTS_SESSION_INFOW(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("SessionId", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("pWinStationName", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ("State", ctypes.c_int)]

ppSessionInfo = WTS_SESSION_INFOW()
pCount = ctypes.c_ulong()
ctypes.windll.wtsapi32.WTSEnumerateSessionsW(0, 0, 1, ctypes.byref(ppSessionInfo), ctypes.byref(pCount))
```

pCount.value returns the correct number of instances running, however ppSessionInfo.SessionId returns a single large integer that does not match any current session id.

The MS documentation says ppSessionInfo should be an array of WTS_SESSION_INFOW structures, however I am not sure how to accomplish this?

I am able to accomplish the above using win32ts.WTSEnumerateSessions() and win32ts.WTSQuerySessionInformation() however I am limited to what imports are available to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from this post: [python ctypes, pass double pointer by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30324758/11307485) I was able to resolve my issue.

Here is the solution:

```
ppSessionInfo = ctypes.POINTER(WTS_SESSION_INFOW)()
pCount = ctypes.c_ulong()
ctypes.windll.wtsapi32.WTSEnumerateSessionsW(0, 0, 1, ctypes.byref(ppSessionInfo), ctypes.byref(pCount))

for index in range(pCount.value):
    ppSessionInfo[index].SessionId
    ppSessionInfo[index].State
    ppSessionInfo[index].pWinStationName
```

Writing out the problem helped me think of better ways to search for what I needed to accomplish.