# Ctypes, python. How to pass back a pointer to a C dynamically allocated double array in one of the function arguments?

Tags: python, c, arrays, pointers

I have a C function `void get_data(int &len, double* data)`, which dynamically allocates the memory for data (size is not known in advance) and returns a pointer to the data. I would like to call it from python using ctypes.

The version with `double* data = get_data(int &len)` is working fine, but I need the one which passes the pointer via an argument, as I have several data vectors.

I've tried many different ways but nothing works:

```
fun = cfun.get_data
fun.argtypes = [ct.c_int, ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)]
fun.restype = None

len = ct.c_int()
data_ptr = ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)()

fun(len, data_ptr)
```

`bool(data_ptr)` -- NULL -- it's not mutable, so stays at NULL
after the C function assigns the new value to it. 
I tried `ct.byref(data_ptr)`, e.t.c. but haven't been able to get the
data out.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `void get_data(int &len, double* data)` which dynamically allocates the memory for data (size is not known in advance).

This won't work even in C. You passing **value** of a pointer into function. Changing this value won't be visible outside. You should have `double** data` ,e.g.pointer to pointer to double if you want to allocate inside of `get_data` and pass pointer outside.

```
void get_data(int *len, double** data)
{
  *len=12;
  *data=malloc(*len);

  //fill data
  for(i=0;i<*len;++i) (*data)[i]=<something>;

  return;
}
```

and here is your answer:
[Python and ctypes: how to correctly pass "pointer-to-pointer" into DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213095/python-and-ctypes-how-to-correctly-pass-pointer-to-pointer-into-dll)

Comment: Great, many thanks, it (almost works now). Indeed the error is in my C --  brain freeze... The only change is (*data)[i] = <something>;  Perhaps it's just my compiler being too picky -- but it segfaults otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it should be `(*data)[i]`. `[]` has higher precedence, so without parens it is executed first, and `*` later.