# Pass parameter of type pointer to pointer to a C function using ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

The definition of my `C` function is -

```
foo(int64_t* total_length,
const int8_t* fromtags,
int64_t fromtagsoffset,
const int32_t* fromindex,
int64_t fromindexoffset,
int64_t length,
int64_t** offsetsraws,
int64_t* offsetsoffsets)
```

I can load it via `ctypes` in `Python` as -

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.CDLL("....")
name = "foo"
funcC = getattr(lib, name)
```

I can set the types of arguments it takes -

```
funcC.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int8), ctypes.c_int64, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32), ctypes.c_int64, ctypes.c_int64, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64)), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64))
```

I assign the values that are to be passed to funcC like -

```
temparr = [0]*30
total_length = ((ctypes.c_int64)*30)(*temparr)
temparr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
fromtags = ((ctypes.c_int8)*len(temparr))(*temparr)
fromtagsoffset = 1
temparr = [1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 7, 3, 8, 3, 8, 8]
fromindex = ((ctypes.c_int32)*len(temparr))(*temparr)
fromindexoffset = 0
length = 3
temparr = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
offsetsoffsets = ((ctypes.c_int64)*len(temparr))(*temparr)
```

For the argument with type pointer to pointer, I assign the values like -

```
temparr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
offsetsraws = ctypes.pointer((ctypes.c_int64 * len(temparr))(*temparr))
```

Then I create a `list` with the arguments -

```
testsc = [total_length, fromtags, fromtagsoffset, fromindex, fromindexoffset, length, offsetsraws, offsetsoffsets]
```

I finally pass the arguments to `funcC` -

```
funcC(*testsc)
```

but I get an error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 7: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_LP_c_long instance instead of LP_c_long_Array_16
```

How should I fix this error?

Is it because I am making a mistake when assigning the `offsetsraws` argtype as `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64))`?

I found a similar question - [Python and ctypes: how to correctly pass "pointer-to-pointer" into DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213095/python-and-ctypes-how-to-correctly-pass-pointer-to-pointer-into-dll) but the difference is that in that question, the pointer to pointer being passed does not have an assigned value during input and more importantly, is not represented as a 2D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

If you have a pointer to an unidimensional array (*~90%+* of the cases), a simple cast from *int64[]* to *int64** will do. 
If however, you have a 2 dimensional array, things get more complicated, as you have to handle each individual unidimensional array (row) separately (*e.g.* [[SO]: How can i cast a double pointer ctype to numpy array? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781199/how-can-i-cast-a-double-pointer-ctype-to-numpy-array/58784385#58784385) (and other *URL*s it references)).

Here's an example for the former case.

> ```
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> gtc = ct.windll.kernel32.GetTickCount  # This function does NOT take arguments. I used it for DEMO PURPOSES ONLY !!! Basically, it's Undefined Behavior.
> >>> gtc.argtypes = [ct.POINTER(ct.POINTER(ct.c_int64))]
> >>>
> >>> arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> >>>
> >>> arr_ct = ct.pointer((ct.c_int64 * len(arr))(*arr))  # Original variant
> >>>
> >>> gtc(arr_ct)  # Will throw exception
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_LP_c_longlong instance instead of LP_c_longlong_Array_16
> >>>
> >>> arr_ct = ct.pointer(ct.cast((ct.c_int64 * len(arr))(*arr), ct.POINTER(ct.c_int64)))  # cast the (inner) array to pointer
> >>>
> >>> gtc(arr_ct)
> 250935781
> ```